# textarea and button for accepting input

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following which is supposed to open up a text area, let the user input data, capture the data in a variable called var, then show a button which says "click here" and after the click writes to the screen the var + "i did it".  However, I don't yet know how to allow the user to input his data.  When the textarea appears, there is no extra button to click and, as soon as I click in the textarea to write data I just get, written to the screen, nullididit, as if the script treated my textarea as the button itself.  Obviously I don't understand how to allow the user to enter his data and have the extra button to be clicked to signal that data entry is over.  Can someone explain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
function getText() {
    var str=document.getElementById("txtArea");
document.write(str + "i did it");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id = "txtArea> </textarea>
<input type = "button" value="click here" onclick = "getText();" />
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract value from textarea, here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4jH8s/

Code:

```
function getText() {
  var area = document.getElementById("txtArea");
  str = area.value // here we got value
  alert(str + " i did it");
}
```

Comment: Mark this answer as correct please or just vote it UP along with @TommyBs answer

Answer (score 1):

As well as the tips about using .value from @Feanor's answer try adding a closing " after id="txtArea as well as you've got a mismatch of quotes. This will cause your tags not to be  closed properly. This would most likely cause the onclick to be part of the textarea as the browser tries to correct your html

Also you aren't using jQuery in your code so can remove the script tag for jquery

Finally instead of document.write trying adding another div and appending to the html of that such as

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

<script>
function getText() {
    var str=document.getElementById("txtArea").value;
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +=str + " i did it";
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id = "txtArea"> </textarea>
<input type = "button" value="click here" onclick = "getText();" />
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As this is better than using document.write

Answer (score 0):

If the code you pasted is the exact code you are testing, then part of your issue may be the missing double quote on the id attribute for the textarea.  Also, `document.getElementById("txtArea")` will return an object instead of the text value that you are looking for. Instead you can use `document.getElementById("txtArea").value` to get the text value.  If you just want to show the test, you may want to use `alert(str + "i did it")` instead of `document.write(str + "i did it")` which will overwrite the content in document.

Here's your code with the changes I mentioned that I tested in Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
function getText() {
    var str=document.getElementById("txtArea").value;
alert(str + "i did it");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id = "txtArea"> </textarea>
<input type = "button" value="click here" onclick = "getText();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery easy, simple and neat code...

```
$('input').click(function() {

    var text = $('#txtArea').val();

        alert(text);

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jH8s/9/)

Comment: This still wouldn't address his issue of the onclick firing on the wrong element. Also, although jQuery is useful he hasn't tagged it in the question (though he is including it) as such and may be trying to learn good old plain javascript

Comment: Give button an a "ID" and use that instead of input..may be i just thought just because i  saw jquery link :D

Comment: I appreciate where you're coming from, and jquery would be quicker, but I also think it's important he grasped why his current code wasn't working. I wasn't having a swipe at your answer either just in case you thought my first comment seemed rude!